# linux - override max width of top command

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I want to write the output of `top` command into a file.

By default, top command cuts the lines in the middle and not showing all the arguments.

When I try to run

```
COLUMNS=1000 top -c -b -n 1 > /tmp/output.txt
```

it doesn't work, I read that there is a limit of 512 columns.

My question is - how can I properly override this number for only this command? or maybe set it in the system and revert it back after executing the command?

Comment: It appears that the maximum setting of COLUMNS for the `top` command is 512. You could get the top source code and change it.

Comment: In `top.h` at https://github.com/soarpenguin/procps-3.0.5/blob/master/top.h you will find `#define SCREENMAX   512` and some explanation.